# adtfdat how to record data with this file format

Tags: adtf

I am playing with ADTF 3 assist to learn how to create plugins. I have read all tutorials from digitalwerk and I have now a good background on how to manage cmake, VS2017 C++, configuration editor, services and so on. I have also compiled some of the conan repository applications and plugins. Now I am in need to record an adtfdat file format to gather CAN and Video data and play it in Configuration Editor. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need for gathering CAN and Video Data the additional Device-Toolbox. This toolbox provides the specific stream type.
They also provide additional examples for gathering video samples and handling CAN, CAN FD and FlexRay streams.

Comment: Hi Benedict, Thanks for your answer. I followed your suggestion and installed the DeviceToolbox. I Run through the 4 Sessions and the one that I want to work next is the Direct Show Capture because it works straight with a capture and so far no adtfdat file needed. I would like to know if it is possible to generate an adtfdat file with 2 streams, one captured from the Demo Direct Capture and the other from the CAN Configure Decoder.

Comment: I would like to inform to whom is going to compile the devicetoolbox source code from the solution adtf_device_examples, to generate the plugins, please include the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\include to the demo_direct_show_capture_source project

Comment: HI Antoine, you can record any stream of any type in an adtfdat file, its like zip container of different data (streams) using the same time base (to replay like exactly like live bahaviour). Simply use the ADTFDAT File Recorder and connect any stream you like to store. Have a look at the example recording session within ADTF and adapt for your use case.

Comment: Hi Benedict and C-3PFLO. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.